# Google Apps Script Duration Division

Tags: google-apps-script

I am struggling to get propper duration value after division of a given total time duration.

Here is an example of the function. This is an abbreviated version of the real function. In the real function I am looping through a range and summing each row duration (cells set to format Time: h:mm:ss) into totDur. I took the value of this from the larger function and just explicitly set the value for this example. The thing that is confusing is that this method works fine for about 25 other duration division calculations in the same function, but not this one. I have a feeling its related to data type or something to that effect.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  var totDur=new Date();
  var totRev=137;
  var totCtr=82
  totDur.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  
  totDur=-301170516818000;
  
  Logger.log('TOT DUR:'+totDur)
  var nTime = new Date();
  nTime.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  var diffGm=totDur-nTime;
  var diffRev=totDur-nTime;
  
  var divGm=diffGm/totCtr;
  var divRev=diffRev/totRev;
  
  Logger.log('TOT DUR: '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(totDur), 'UTC', 'HH:mm:ss'))
  Logger.log('BY REV: '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(diffRev), 'UTC', 'HH:mm:ss')+'/'+totCtr+'='+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(divRev), 'UTC', 'HH:mm:ss'))
  Logger.log('BY GM: '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(diffGm), 'UTC', 'HH:mm:ss')+'/'+totRev+'='+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(divGm), 'UTC', 'HH:mm:ss'))
  
  
}
```

Here is the resulting Log Output:

[17-01-18 10:20:33:442 MST] TOT DUR UNFORMATTED: -301170516818000
[17-01-18 10:20:33:443 MST] TOT DUR FORMATTED: 03:06:22
[17-01-18 10:20:33:444 MST] BY REV: 03:06:22/82=23:50:50
[17-01-18 10:20:33:445 MST] BY GM: 03:06:22/137=01:12:31

TOT DUR value is correct, but the other two are not. I assume I am performing the division improperly. Obviously 3hr 6min 22sec divided by 82 is not 23hrs.

Comment: dates are just the milliseconds since 1970 with some fancy methods on top, do you really need to use dates for this? I'd rather try to parse the durations from the timestamps taken from the spreadsheet and then parse it back after the calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your comment made me rethink the process. I ended up converting the Value to milliseconds and performed the division on that. After then reformatted in HH:mm:ss. Way less code and values are all correct now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking the process. After converting the value to milliseconds i performed the division and then used a pretty simple function from the below link to convert back to an HH:mm:ss format.

https://coderwall.com/p/wkdefg/converting-milliseconds-to-hh-mm-ss-mmm